# Why my form inside an <p:accordionPanel> cannot be reached from outside?

Tags: java, forms, primefaces

I am doing simple forms with an `<p:accordionPanel>` with primefaces, basically, at each tab I have a form, so, my `<h:form>` is after the `<tab>` tag, as it should... and the  starts after the `<p:accordionPanel>` to finish always before next tab starts and so on...

In theory, all is ok, the problem is that I cannot make an update from my form, even if I have the structure

```
<p:accordionPanel>
   <h:form id="formInformation">
      <p:tab title="Information">
          <p:panel id="myPanel">
```

Wheter my tab is after the form of before, everytime I try to make an update to an element inside that form it says the element simply doesnt exist, why is this problem? is there any special limitation on the tabs I should know?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I am trying to refer to my component at this way :formInformation:myPanel

No success...I always refer my components like that, for some reason, everything inside the `<tab>` is not reachable

EDIT 2:

I am calling it from here:

```
<h:form id="main">
    <p:panel id="mainPanel">
    ...
    ...
    <commandButton id="button" ......  update=":formInformation:myPanel">
```

Comment: From where are you trying to refer to `myPanel`? Inside `myPanel`? Or outside of `formInformation`? Or even somewhere else?

Comment: from outside of formInformation

Comment: Then you need to provide more code. Show us the code segment which is refering to `myPanel` and everything 'between' them. There must be some other NamingContainer in between!

Comment: thanks, I posted a sample.

Comment: Putting a form inside an accordionPanel may screw up your DOM. However, the correct naming would be:

Answer (score 0):

how do you refer you component?
 if you want to update a component inside a form from outside you have to use `update=":formID:componentID"` or simply `update=":formID"` to update whole components in your form

Comment: Thanks, I am updating an specific panel inside my form, I dont want to update all because I also have other submits I cant make, and since I cannot use separate <h:form> inside my tab element, I have to process only parts of the code, I try to do it processing only certain panels

Comment: this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018533/primefaces-update-from-inside-another-form

Answer (score 0):

Because your component is defined inside another naming container.

You have to either give the 'full path' to the `h:form` like `myPanel:formInformation` or use the 'wildcard' `:` like `:formInformation` within the `update` attribute value.

See my more detailed answer [Naming Container in JSF2/PrimeFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543510/naming-container-in-jsf2-primefaces/13545099#13545099)

Answer (score 0):

Putting a form inside an `accordionPanel` will screw up your DOM and make the components inside not render. You should put the form OUTSIDE of the accordion panel, and correct naming would be:

`:form_id:accordionPanel_id:element_id`

However, you can put the `form` inside a `tab` (as to have the following:)

```
<p:tab>
  <h:form>
    ...
  </h:form>
</p:tab>
```

Then the naming would be:

`:accordionPanel_id:form_id:element_id`

In your specific case, it would be:

```
<p:accordionPanel id="myAccordion">
  ...
  <p:tab title="Information">
    <h:form id="formInformation">
      <p:panel id="myPanel">
        ...
      </p:panel>
    </h:form>
  </p:tab>
  ...
</p:accordionPanel>
```

Calling from a different container:

```
<p:commandButton id="button" ......  update=":myAccordion:formInformation:myPanel">
```